# $_FILES is always empty after trying to upload files

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time getting file uploads to work in php.

- I'm running php 5, so I should have the $_FILES variable
- My php.ini shows that file uploading is on, and that I'm not trying to upload a file that's too big
- There's enough space on my disk

Expected: information about uploaded files. 
Got: empty $_FILES

Here's my form/script. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<body> 

<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== "POST"):  ?> 

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 
<label for="file">Upload a file:</label> 
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br/> 
<button type="submit">Analyze</button> 
</form>    

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"):  

    print_r($_FILES);  // debugging

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) 
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "<p>Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB</p>";
        echo "<p>Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file. Please make sure your file is a plain text file and is small enough for this program to analyze.";
}

endif; ?> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `enctype` is missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot your encoding type attribute in your `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 4):

By default form data is submitted using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding (this is the same format as used in a query string for a GET request) which doesn't support file data.

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data):

> If the entry's type is "file", replace its value with the file's name only.

You need to use the `multipart/form-data` encoding. You can specify this with the [`enctype` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype)

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Update this way:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
```